# Retrieve RGB value of a coordinate in a Matplotlib Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates, polygon, rgb

I have a code which generates a filled polygon with black color. Please find below the code snippet which generates the same.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coord = [[0.11,1.11], [2,1], [2,2], [1,2], [0.5,1.5],[1.5,1.5]]
coord.append(coord[0]) #repeat the first point to create a 'closed loop'

xs, ys = zip(*coord) #create lists of x and y values

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xs,ys)


plt.fill(xs,ys,"black")
plt.show()
```

This is the ouptut which I see:
[image]

Now, if I give a Coordinate [x,y] how can I get RGB value of that particluar Coordinate?
(In our Case it it would be either Black or White).

Comment: I don't know if it has function to get it but using `PIL` you could draw polygon on image and get pixel color directly or convert to numpy's array and get value from array. Problem is that pixel in image use integer coordinates (x,y) and you would have to recalculate it for float coordinates.

Comment: If you are able to export the `matplotlib` to a file, reading the RGB value of an image pixel is straightforward with multiple tools available (including `PIL` as @furas mentions).